# MongoDB php add tz offset to aggregate query and average output

Tags: php, mongodb, timezone, aggregation-framework

I know that mongoDB (php-driver) saves the date as ISODate in Milliseconds UTC, so i have to add a offset for my timezone (GMT +2:00) to the aggregate query.

```
$dateStart = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("now 00:00:00") * 1000);
$dateEnd   = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(time() * 1000);

$queryHours = [
            ['$match' => ['date' => ['$gte' => $dateStart, '$lte' => $dateEnd]]],
            ['$project' => ['date' => ['$add' => ['$date', 2*60*60000]]]],
            ['$group' => ['_id' => ['$hour' => '$date'], 'average' => ['$avg' => '$zapi.apiRes.curlHeader.total_time']]],
            ['$sort' => ['_id' => 1]],
        ];
```

The $hour result seems to be correct, but i get no "average" result and i doesn't see my failure since days, staring at the code. :(

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e4e3ca135d9e038242b248"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-05T12:32:10Z"),
    [...]
    "zapi" : {
            "apiRes" : {
                    "apiCall" : {
                            [...]
                    },
                    "curlHeader" : {
                            "url" : "http://api:/api/foo",
                            "http_code" : 204,
                            "total_time" : 0.02906399999999998,
                            [...]
                    },
            }
    },
```

}

I know that mongoDB working on this feature nativ: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28611.

Thanks and best regards,

lun4tic

Comment: Can you share a sample doc from your collection ?

Comment: Sure, i added the link to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `$project` stage with `$addFields` if you are on 3.4 version.

```
$queryHours = 
[
      ['$match' => ['date' => ['$gte' => $dateStart, '$lte' => $dateEnd]]],
      ['$addFields' => ['date' => ['$add' => ['$date', 2*60*60000]]]],
      ['$group' => ['_id' => ['$hour' => '$date'], 'average' => ['$avg' => '$zapi.apiRes.curlHeader.total_time']]],
      ['$sort' => ['_id' => 1]],
];
```

Or

You can simply move the timezone arithmetic from `$project` stage into `$group` stage.

```
 ['$group' => ['_id' => ['$hour' => [ '$add' => ['$date', 2*60*60000] ] ], 'average' => ['$avg' => '$zapi.apiRes.curlHeader.total_time']]],
```

Comment: Move from $project stage into $group doesn't work, i get the error: `can't convert from BSON type missing to Date`.

Anyway, the '$addFields' solution is smart and works fine, didn't know about $addFields, thank you! :)

Comment: You are welcome. I just ran `$queryHours = [
            ['$match' => ['date' => ['$gte' => $dateStart, '$lte' => $dateEnd]]],
            ['$group' => ['_id' => ['$hour' => [ '$add' => ['$date', 2*60*60000] ] ], 'average' => ['$avg' => '$zapi.apiRes.curlHeader.total_time']]],
            ['$sort' => ['_id' => 1]],
        ];` and it worked fine. Its likely you have some values which are not date types.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, works fine, both solutions from you. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error should be the project phase. You have to add `'zapi.apiRes.curlHeader.total_time' => 1` so try this:

```
$queryHours = [
            ['$match' => ['date' => ['$gte' => $dateStart, '$lte' => $dateEnd]]],
            ['$project' => ['date' => ['$add' => ['$date', 2*60*60000]], 'zapi.apiRes.curlHeader.total_time' => 1]],
            ['$group' => ['_id' => ['$hour' => '$date'], 'average' => ['$avg' => '$zapi.apiRes.curlHeader.total_time']]],
            ['$sort' => ['_id' => 1]],
        ];
```